# Какое сказуемое в предложении?

Tags: сказуемые, синтаксический-разбор

Какое сказуемое в предложении "Девочку звали Алисой"? Я думаю, что "звали Алисой".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В предложении "Девочку звали Алисой" -  составное именное сказуемое.

Comment: Только не ''какое'', а где.

Answer (score 1):

> Какое сказуемое в предложении "Девочку
> звали Алисой"? Я думаю, что "звали
> Алисой".

Правильно думаете.